# Espresso startActivity that depends on Intent

Tags: android, testing, android-intent, android-espresso

I have the following situation.

My activity has a fragment that depends of a Serializable Object. Here is my onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MyObject myObj = (MyObj) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myobj");

    if(myObj != null) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.container, MyFragment.newInstance(myObj));
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

But in my Espresso test I simply can't pass the intent to the activity before it's created. I tried with setActivityIntent in several ways but cant figure out how to make it work.

Here is my last attempt:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.espresso.Espresso;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import org.junit.Before;

import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;

public class MyActivityTest extends

     ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {

        private MyActivity activity;
        private MyObject myObj;

        public MyActivityTest() {
            super(MyActivity.class);
        }

        @Before
        protected void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
            injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
            myObj = MyObject.mockObject();
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("myobj", myObj);
            setActivityIntent(i);

        }

        public void testName(){
            Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.name)).check(matches(withText(myObj.getObjName())));
        }

    }
```

I've searched a lot but nothing works. `MyObject` is always null in the test. I think this should be simple. What am I'm missing?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: you don't need @Before, because this is a JUnit 3 test not a JUnit 4 test.

Comment: Solved, the problem was with my mock... Sorry to bother.

Comment: Solution in Kotlin taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56694061/6248208)

Answer (score 41):

You can define the Intent to be used in this way

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyActivityTestTest {

    private MyObject myObj;

    @Rule
    // third parameter is set to false which means the activity is not started automatically
    public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> mActivityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(MyActivity.class, false, false);


    @Test
    public void testName() {

          myObj = MyObject.mockObject();
          Intent i = new Intent();
          i.putExtra("myobj", myObj);
          mActivityRule.launchActivity(i);

         //...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can override the [ActivityTestRule.getActivityIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/ActivityTestRule.html#getActivityIntent()) method and return a required Intent:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MyActivity> mActivityRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<MyActivity>(MyActivity.class){

    @Override
    protected Intent getActivityIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("myobj", myObj);
        return intent;
    }
};
```

Comment: Where are you passing `myObj` into this Rule?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are actually starting the activity anywhere.

Try calling `getActivity()` on the first line of testName().

This will launch the activity that you passed into the super constructor.

Comment: I tried to call `getActivity()` on the first line of test method and in the last line of `setUp()` but didn't work =/

Comment: Solved, the problem was with my mock... Sorry to bother.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2022;**

```java
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario;
import androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyTest extends Assert {

@Test
public void testMyMethod_shouldBlaBlaBla() {
    Intent myIntent = ...;
    ActivityScenario.launch(myIntent).onActivity(activity -> {
        // Tests go here, which runs on UI-Thread.
        assertTrue(false);
    });
}

}
```

> **Note** that `@UiThreadTest` (i.e. `androidx.test.annotation.UiThreadTest`) is NOT used.