# Mocking Intent Extras in Espresso Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-intent, android-testing, android-espresso

I’m trying to launch `Activity` in Espresso. The thing is I want to put mocked extras to the `Intent` I’m using to launch the `Activity`. Here is the example.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public final class NiceActivityTester
{
    @Rule
    public final ActivityTestRule<NiceActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(NiceActivity.class, true, false);

    @Test
    public void justStartPlease() {
        NiceThing niceThing = Mockito.mock(NiceThing.class);
        Mockito.when(niceThing.getName()).thenReturn("Nice!");

        Intent intent = new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), NiceActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("NICE_THING", niceThing);

        activityRule.launchActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately unmarshalling `Parcelable` fails.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.application/app.application.activity.NiceActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: NiceThing_Proxy
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: NiceThing_Proxy
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2295)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:755)
    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:5088)
    at app.application.NiceActivity.getNiceThing(NiceActivity.java:40)
    at app.application.NiceActivity.setUpToolbar(NiceActivity.java:30)
    at app.application.NiceActivity.onCreate(NiceActivity.java:20)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:534)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
```

Is there any way to use mocked extras with `Intent`? Maybe some best practices regarding this area?

I really don’t want to make constructors for every model I’m using, some of these classes are quite complex with a dozen of fields. Spying on the extra or the `Intent` using Mockito doesn’t help.

Comment: check this: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/index.html (especially `intent stubbing` section)

Comment: `Intent` stubbing is for mocking the result when using `Activity#startActivityForResult`. This does not apply in my case.

Comment: Could you solve your problem?If yes then please post the solution

Answer (score 12):

Use `ActivityTestRule` and override `getActivityIntent`

Example found [here](https://github.com/barend/android-espresso-intent-sample/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/nl/garvelink/blog/espressointentsample/MainActivityLaunchIntentTest.java)

```
public class MainActivityLaunchIntentTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class) {
                @Override
                protected Intent getActivityIntent() {
                    Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
                    Intent result = new Intent(targetContext, MainActivity.class);
                    result.putExtra("Name", "Earth");
                    return result;
                }
            };

    @Test
    public void shouldShowHelloEarth() {
        onView(withId(R.id.main__tv_hello)).check(matches(withText("Hello Earth!")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work with latest Android Test updates and libraries? Is there better method to do this in 2018?

Comment: im trying to get the extra from the intent in oncreate(). I want to put my on Extra into the intent. so essentially. I have to stub / mock the Activity getIntent() method. how can i achieve this?

Comment: How about using ActivityScenarioRule?

Comment: @quangkid @filthy_wizard @Ewoks I have used `ActivityScenarioRule` in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73405821/1467923) above.

Answer (score 8):

Kotlin solution for this:

```
@get:Rule
val mActivityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<TheActivity> =
        object : ActivityTestRule<TheActivity>(TheActivity::class.java) {
            override fun getActivityIntent(): Intent {
                val targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
                return Intent(targetContext, TheActivity::class.java).apply {
                    putExtra(TheActivity.ACTIVITY_TITLE,
                            targetContext.resources.getString(R.string.the_text))
                    putExtra(TheActivity.SETTING_TITLE,
                            targetContext.resources.getString(R.string.the_title))
                    putExtra(TheActivity.SCREEN_TYPE,
                            TheActivity.ScreenType.AMOUNT.name)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't forget to put in gradle file `androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'`

Answer (score 0):

In recent updates, [`ActivityTestRule` was declared a deprecated class](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule). The Android Developers documentation recommends using [`ActivityScenario`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario) or [`ActivityScenarioRule`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule).

Assuming that we are using `ActivityScenarioRule` and your test code as the base example, the solution to include an `Intent` would then be as follows:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public final class NiceActivityTester
{
    @Rule
    public final ActivityScenarioRule<NiceActivity> scenarioRule = 
        new ActivityScenarioRule<>(
            new Intent(
                InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),
                NiceActivity.class)
                .putExtra("your_extra1_key", yourExtra1Value)            // first extra
                .putExtra("your_extra2_key", yourExtra2Value));          // second extra
                .putExtra("your_extra3_key", createParcelableObject())); // parcelable extra
                                                                         // you may add more

    // An example function that creates and returns a parcelable object
    ObjectType createParcelableObject() {
        ObjectType parcelableObject = new ObjectType();
        parcelableObject.setAttribute1("attribute1");
        parcelableObject.setAttribute2("attribute2");
        parcelableObject.setAttribute3("attribute3");
        .
        . // more attributes setting, for example
        .
        return parcelableObject;
    }

    @Test
    public void justStartPlease() {
        ActivityScenarioRule<NiceActivity> = scenarioRule.getScenario();

        // The rest would be your test code
        
    }
}
```

Here are a few things that you might want to take note of:

- The [`getTargetContext`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/InstrumentationRegistry#getTargetContext()), or technically, the [`InstrumentRegistry`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/InstrumentationRegistry) class itself, is now deprecated. The documentation recommends using [`ApplicationProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ApplicationProvider). Therefore, instead of `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()`, you may replace with [`ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/core/app/ApplicationProvider#getApplicationContext()). Either way, I have tested and verified that both work at the time of this answer's posting.
- With `ActivityScenarioRule`, you are able to supply an `Intent` as its argument. Hence, you can include extras when launching your `Activity`. Simply create a new `Intent` and include the `Activity` that you intend to launch like the code sample above.
- To successfully include a parcelable object to your intent, you have to include your object when instantiating your `ActivityScenarioRule` class/object. In the example code above, a function has been written to create and return a parcelable object *while* creating the `ActivityScenarioRule`. The documentation specifically mentions that the class "*[launches a given activity before the test starts and closes after the test](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule)*". So, whatever it is that you need to include for your activity, do it when you're instantiating your `ActivityScenarioRule`.