# Pass mocked class in an Android intent

Tags: android, mockito, instrumentation

Is there a way to put a mocked class in an (android) intent during an instrumentation test. Something along the following lines?

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
@Mock(serializable = true)
SomeClass someClass; //Defined also as implementing Serializable
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mMainActivityTestRule = new
        ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class,false,false);
@Rule
public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Test
public void testGetQuote() throws Exception {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putSerializable("someClass", someClass);
    i.putExtras(b); //Fails! 
    // more code here
}
```

The above code fails with  `Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object`

Any ideas?

--- Edited
The code using the @Spy annotation looks as follows:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
@Spy
SomeClass someClass; //Same behaviour when @Mock was used
@Spy
Intent intent;
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mMainActivityTestRule = new
        ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class,false,false);
@Rule
public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Test
public void testGetQuote() throws Exception {
   when(someClass.getFoo(anyString())).thenReturn(expectedAnswer);
   when(intent.getSerializableExtra(anyString())).thenReturn(someClass);

   //Intent object has identifier of, e.g. @5650 here
   intent.putExtra("someClass",someClass);
   mMainActivityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);
   //more Code here
}
```

...

```
//inside the Main activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Intent has different id here, e.g. @5850
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // intent.getSerializableExtra("someClass")  returns null
    //...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to spy the Intent and make putExtras return the bundle mocked class?

Comment: This does not work. Aparrently when the Activity is called some copy of the initial Intent is passed to it, and not the intent itself.

Comment: Post the code you did

Comment: Not sure if you have seen this already, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200598/2231099