# Espresso with a listview

Tags: listview, android-espresso

For example, when we use Espresso with a listview, we're supposed to populate it prior to using it right? I couldn't figured it out how to do that properly.

I mean is it possible via Espresso itself or do I need to set it up in a method with a @Before annotation.

Thanks

Comment: Espresso is a test framework. You should use perform a ViewAction to interact with your app. I don't understand your question well.

Comment: Yes it is. No worries about that. But you see the API allows you to access activity directly. Assume that you've a list in it and want to click an item on it. But the listview should be populated beforehand right? And my question comes here. How that list is should be initialized or populated?  Since there's no real execution flow performed, your list might depend on other works needed to be done out of the it's owner activity lifecycle.

Comment: May be you want to pass the intent when start the activity? In that case, the following link may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32227345/1270534

Comment: This might be the only option but also requires changes in the original Activity to make it sort of testable.

Answer (score 0):

You seem like a rookie in Espresso, like me. 
Here is how I understand the Espresso process:

```
1. When you make a test, first you need to have a rule:

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

2. Then you create a test method:

    @Test
    public void helloWorld()
    {
        onView(withId(R.id.txtHello)).check(matches(withText("Hello World!")));
    }
```

(if MainActivity contains a view with id R.id.txtHello and it contains as text "Hello World!", the test will pass).

Now if you run the test, the MainActivity class will open and will load everything into the class. Espresso will wait until the activity loads all the stuff inside. After everything is finished, the test will run.

So don't worry about anything regarding the loading process, because Espresso test will start only when the UIthread will be empty.

Good luck!

Comment: Agreed. But this is not my problem. I don't populate my list DATA in the activity. It's loaded beforehand in the model layer.

Answer (score 0):

The "onView" method is used to reference "regular" views such as TextView, EditText and Button.  But to reference "special" views like ListView and RecyclerView you need to use the "onData" method instead.

This about "onView" being for views with data that is completely visible on the screen.  The "onData" method is used when the specific item of data may not be visible and may require the user/test to scroll to it.

Comment: Hi. Thx for the afford but this is not the issue. The issue is how to populate the underlying list.