# Launching Activity with extra attached to Intent in Instrumented test, running on espresso and JUnit 5

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-espresso, junit5

I'd like to launch my `ActivityScenarioExtension` with an extra attached to the `startActivityIntent`. The extra-less scenario extension launching, which works just as intended, I carry out via

```
internal class TestMainActivity{
    @JvmField
    @RegisterExtension
    val scenarioExtension = ActivityScenarioExtension.launch<MainActivity>()

    @BeforeEach
    fun recreateActivity(scenario: ActivityScenario<MainActivity>){
        scenario.recreate()
    }
}
```

, however I'm not sure as to how to add in the required extra.

Not having found any real reference addressing how to achieve that, I simply tried

```
@JvmField
@RegisterExtension
val scenarioExtension = ActivityScenarioExtension.launch<MainActivity>(
    Intent().putParcelableArrayListExtra("CROP_URIS", ArrayList())
)
```

, which however led to

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { (has extras) }
at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker.startActivity(InstrumentationActivityInvoker.java:402)
at androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker.startActivity(InstrumentationActivityInvoker.java:437)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:265)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:226)
at de.mannodermaus.junit5.ActivityScenarioExtension$Companion$launch$2.invoke(ActivityScenarioExtension.kt:130)
at de.mannodermaus.junit5.ActivityScenarioExtension$Companion$launch$2.invoke(ActivityScenarioExtension.kt:130)
at de.mannodermaus.junit5.ActivityScenarioExtension.beforeEach(ActivityScenarioExtension.kt:156)
```

The implementation propositions exclusively concerning JUnit 4 in turn, I've found in [Espresso startActivity that depends on Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752303/espresso-startactivity-that-depends-on-intent), I didn't quite manage to transfer into the realm of JUnit 5 and its newly introduced Extension model.

Thanks in advance for whatever kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private val intent = Intent(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity::class.java).apply {
    putParcelableArrayListExtra("CROP_URIS", ArrayList())
}

@Rule
@JvmField
val activity = ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity>(intent)
```